# How to make a script to use in Chrome

Tags: google-chrome

I need to make a series of action by a single press for example: I want the PC to press "TAB" then "12345", "67890" after that "TAB" and finally "ENTER".

I will use this in web page using Chrome

Comment: You can try and install the "Selenium" plug-in for Chrome. You can then record a sequence of actions and play them back - will you always be entering the same data each click?

Comment: http://www.seleniumhq.org/

Comment: Thank you so much , I really appreciate that . It worked on firefox perfectly  but if you have the link to chrome extension could you sent it plz